# Common location to trap DbEntityValidationException and obtain EntityValidationErrors for Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

To get the specific validation error messages from Entity Framework, I have to wrap all my [DbContext].SaveChanges() in a Try/Catch such as:

```
public bool Delete(int id)
{
    using (var db = new MainContext())
    {

        db.Entry(new Borrower { Id = id }).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            ex.Data.Add("Validation_Errors_from_DbEntityValidationException", Common.LogMessageDbEntityValidationException(ex));
            throw;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

In Common.LogMessageDbEntityValidationException I do:

```
public static string LogMessageDbEntityValidationException(DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

    error.AppendLine("Validation Error details for DbEntityValidationException that has been throw: ");

    foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            error.AppendLine(string.Format("Property: {0} , Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage));
        }
    }

    return error.ToString();
}
```

If I don't do this and just trap errors that bubble-up, the EntityValidationErrors are not available to log, which results in this level of detail is lost.

In my larger projects I have hundreds of these statements. Is there are now trap or subscribe to this error in one central spot, such the class that implements DbContext?

Comment: Override SaveChanges?

Comment: For some reason I thought SaveChanges was invariant but it isn't so I can override it. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: How is the code that calls `Delete` going to discover any errors that occurred? Generally it is deemed a bad idea to just return a boolean from such methods.

Comment: Any errors are bubbled up and caught by the application. You'll notice that the one error trapped (DbEntityValidationException) also rethrows the error. True is only returned when an error is not thrown. I avoid returning void from methods in case I want to convert it to a async function in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just override SaveChanges

Comment: I like the easy solutions!